# Using socket.io with gcm

Tags: android

I have a chat website.I am using socket.io in my web site.I need to do an android app for this site.I will use socket.io in app for real time conversation but also I want to add push notification support with gcm.I know the gcm but I need a roadmap.

**This is my algorithm:**

(In this algorithm,user 1 sends a message to user 2 from web and user 2 uses android app)

1)Get the user 1's message to server

2)Send a ping to user 2 via socket.io

3)If user 2 replies this ping that means user 2 using app right now,send message with socket.io

4)If user 2 doesn't reply this ping that means user 2 was closed the app,server sends a http request to gcm server for send a push notification to user 2.

Is this a good approach ? If you reply is "no" how should be ?

Comment: A periodic ping-pong of gcm's helps reduce random latency spikes. It will keep socket connection alive.

Comment: @Dexter Can you explain more ?